Relations without Relata?
Ladyman’s ontic structural realism posits to the world is comprised of relations without relata. Can somebody please explain what this means conceptually? What are the reasons someone would have for believing that the world consists solely of relations without relata? How could relations give the appearance of individual objects?

Please give some reference to the paper and the passage you refer to, thanks.

From a naive set theoretic point of view a relation is based on pairs of objects. If relatiions are primitive, we may say that objects are "projections" of relations.

@MauroALLEGRANZA - it sounds like the relational formulation merely inverts the ontology vs simplify it. Is that the correct interpetation?

Doesn’t this notion have something of the flavor of category theory?

Added a link to a brief explanation of OSR. Feel free to roll back.

The most common reason is that modal relations between phenomena (counterfactual explanations and regularities) are what is retained in historical theory change, whereas posited objects and substances change, see SEP,  Ontic Structural Realism. Hence, relations are the most plausible candidates for representing "the real". Since relational data can often be compressed in terms of placeholders, representations that introduce objects can be pragmatically beneficial.

@MauroALLEGRANZA What would it mean for objects being “projections” of relations? How can sets exist without individual elements?

@PaulTanenbaum - good point: category theory vs set theory. In the former, objects have no "intrinsec" properties; they are only targets of functions (relations).

The subtitle of Ladyman's "Every Thing Must Go" is "Metaphysics Naturalized." This emphasizes that Ladyman and others are motivated by scientific concerns, especially those of modern physics. Quantum physics is famously difficult to interpret in a way where the world is composed of distinct objects with definite properties. (You might be interested in reading about the Kochen-Specker theorem: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kochen-specker/) Some physicists simply abandon realism in favor of instrumentalism. Others have to get a bit more creative (e.g. the many-worlds interpretation, Bohmian mechanics, dynamical collapse theories, and many more). Interestingly, at least two physicists have developed interpretations that essentially amount to relations without relata: David Mermin's Ithaca interpretation and Carlo Rovelli's relational quantum mechanics. If you're interested, Rovelli wrote a book for laymen called "Helgoland." All this is to say, a possible answer to your second question is that a belief in relations without relata leaves room for both scientific realism and quantum mechanics, and that is not a very easy thing to do.
If you're interested in reasons outside of modern physics, there are apparently similar ideas to 'relations without relata' in Nāgārjuna's thoughts on 'emptiness,' though I can't really speak on that. (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nagarjuna/)
As for your first and third questions, think about a common-sense object like a table. We can instead view a table as a bunch of molecules that are in certain relations with each other. Those molecules in turn are a handful of atoms in relation with each other. These atoms are composed of sub-atomic particles. And so on. At every level, we have objects and relations, but those objects are themselves just relations between other objects. In some sense, what Ladyman is saying is that there is no fundamental level---that it's relations all the way down. Related ideas to this rejection of atomism are 'rainforest realism' and 'real patterns ontology.'
Some comments note that this seems to be related to category theory, and while I don't believe category theory had a big influence on Ladyman, there does seem to be an interesting connection between ontic structural realism and category theory, and others have written on this very idea: https://philpapers.org/rec/EVACTA-3
